# Change in default string contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this default string: `{0} blah blah blah blah {1}` where the `{0}` and `{1}` will be replaced with a value upon loading in a text box.

Example: if `{0} = "CUP"` and `{1} = "GIRLS"`, the string that will be displayed in the text box is `"CUP blah blah blah blah GIRLS"`

Now the issue is this: when the user edits the default message and clicks "Save", how do I replace the {0} = "CUP" and {1} = "GIRLS" in the modified message? (Change in message can happen in which ever part of the original message)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```js
console.log(
  '{0} blah blah blah blah {1}'
  .replace(/\{0}/, 'CUP')
  .replace(/\{1}/, 'GIRLS')
)
```

---

Or store replace content inside an array and then replace with matched content( Even object can be use here ).

```js
var rep = ['CUP', 'GIRLS'];

console.log(
  '{0} blah blah blah blah {1}'
  .replace(/\{(\d+)}/g, function(_, m1) {
    return rep[m1];
  })
)
```

---

**UPDATE :**
Working demo with two text input.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('result'),
  t1 = document.getElementById('text1'),
  t2 = document.getElementById('text2'),
  str = '{0} blah blah blah blah {1}';

function change() {
  div.innerHTML = str
    .replace(/\{0}/, t1.value)
    .replace(/\{1}/, t2.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="change()" id="text1" />
<input type="text" oninput="change()" id="text2" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: How about this scenario (before saving): `foo foo foo CUP foo blah blah GIRLS`? I don't think it will satisfy it.

Comment: why not use `{\d+}` rather than hard code to expect 0 or 1 - then the function could be used to replace an arbitrary number of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can call custom replace function:

```
var replace = function(s,d) {
    return s.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g,function(m,k,v){
        return d[k];
    });
}

var result  = replace("{0} blah blah blah blah {1}", ["hello", "world"]);
console.log(result);

//Returns: hello blah blah blah blah world
```

Or you can add this method to string class (not recommend)

```
String.prototype.rplc = function(data) {
        return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g,function(m,k,v){
            return data[k];
        });
    }

var result = "{0} blah blah blah blah {1}".rplc(["hello", "world"]);
console.log(result);    

//Returns: hello blah blah blah blah world
```